# Compare Dates using LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I need to return a list of items from my database that expire at a pre-specified time on the date supplied by the item. My **erroneous** code is as follows:

```
return All().Where(o => new DateTime(o.expiry_date.Year, o.expiry_date.Month, o.expiry_date.Day, 17, 30, 0) >= DateTime.Now)
```

The error I get is:

**Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities**

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you not use `expiry_date` directly? `.Where(o => o.expiry_date >= DateTime.Now)`.

Comment: It must incorporate the date specified by the item but use the pre-determined time, so unfortunately not. Even making an expiry_date2 property wouldnt work because you'd have to do a ToList() first.

Comment: Go through link bellow..
[Check Dates Only in LINQ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24380028/1833050

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) instead. Maybe [CreateDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime.aspx) method.

So maybe like this:

```
return All().Where(o => EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(o.expiry_date.Year, o.expiry_date.Month, o.expiry_date.Day, 17, 30, 0) >= DateTime.Now)
```

**Update:**

When using EF6, use [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Just for the record, EntityFunctions is deprecated in EF6, replaced by [System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
var result = await db.Articles
          .Where(TruncateTime(x.DateCreated) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now))
          .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use:

```
return All().Where(o => EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(o.expiry_date.Year, o.expiry_date.Month, o.expiry_date.Day, 17, 30, 0) >= DateTime.Now)
```