# Use Linq query to compare date only with DateTime field

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-4

I need to compare just the date only in a Linq query that involves a `datetime` field. However, the syntax below results in the following error message

`The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Does anyone know how to extract just the date out of a `datetime` field?

```
var duplicate = from a in _db.AgentProductTraining
                where a.CourseCode == course.CourseCode &&
                a.DateTaken.Date == course.DateTaken.Date &&
                a.SymNumber == symNumber
                select a;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might seem a little roundabout, but you can use the SqlFunctions class' [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052.aspx) method for doing this. Just pass in both values and use "Day" for finding the difference between them in days (which should be 0 if they are on the same day).

Like the following:

```
from a in _db.AgentProductTraining
                where a.CourseCode == course.CourseCode &&
                SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", a.DateTaken, course.DateTaken) == 0 &&
                a.SymNumber == symNumber
                select a;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the diff be zero if the dates are on different dates, but are spaced at less than one day, say, `Jan-5, 2013 23:30:00` and `Jan-6, 2013 01:30:00`?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work either. Since it's nested in the Linq query, I'm looking into finding out why but not having any luck...

Comment: Did it still throw that exception?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid That is correct: You can only use this method with a LINQ to Entities call. Judging by the fact that there is an object called `_db` I assume that this question has to do with such a query.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()` under the namespace `System.Data.Objects`

Ex.

```
db.Orders.Where(i => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.OrderFinishDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(dtBillDate) && i.Status == "B")
```

Works like charm.

**UPDATE**

This function works only when you querying entities through LINQ. Do not use in LINQ-Object.

For EF6 use DbFunctions.TruncateTime() under System.Data.Entity namespace.

Comment: Hey @AlexAngas, you can check to verify this is working in EF4. which version are you using?

Comment: I used EF5 and got this exception: `System.NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.     at System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(Nullable`1 dateValue)`. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: @AlexAngas This function works only when you querying entities through LINQ. Do not use in LINQ-Object.

Comment: Dear down-voter, no offence in down-voting. But please comment what was missing / can be potentially improved, otherwise it spoils the reputation of the question that might be useful to someone in need.

Comment: EntityFunctions is deprecated in EF6, DbFunctions should be used instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like bellow:

```
var data1 = context.t_quoted_value.Where(x => x.region_name == "Pakistan" 
                        && x.price_date.Value.Year == dt.Year
                        && x.price_date.Value.Month == dt.Month
                        && x.price_date.Value.Day == dt.Day).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

you must use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DateTime dt =course.DateTaken.Date;
var duplicate = from a in _db.AgentProductTraining
                where a.CourseCode == course.CourseCode &&
                a.DateTaken == dt &&
                a.SymNumber == symNumber
                select a;
```

if a.DateTaken contains Time also, then refer these links to modify your date. 
The Date property cannot be used in LINQ To Entities.

[Compare Dates using LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741399/compare-dates-using-linq-to-entities-entity-framework)

['Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083871/date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializers-entity-members)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1793337.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended by doing a similar Date search which I had to consider time (Hour and Minutes portion) also

```
from x in _db.AgentProductTraining
                where 
                       x.CreatedOn.Year == mydacourse.DateTakente.Year
                    && x.CreatedOn.Month == course.DateTaken.Month
                    && x.CreatedOn.Day == course.DateTaken.Day
                    && x.CreatedOn.Hour == course.DateTaken.Hour
                    && x.CreatedOn.Minute == course.DateTaken.Minute
                select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey when I was building a query this below worked

```
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(SearchText); 
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Date.Month == date.Month
                                          && x.Date.Day == date.Day
                                          && x.Date.Year == date.Year);
```

// Let me know if this worked for you as it pulled the date that was searched for me

Comment: you can just do `x.Date == date.Date` or `x.Date.Equals(date.Date)`

Answer (score 0):

A little bit ugly but it works as expected without using any sql functions:

```cs
var sessions = await Db.Set<Sessions>()
    .Where(x => x.Timetable == form.TimetableId)
    .Where(x => x.DateAndTimeOfSession >= form.BookingDate.Date) // <--
    .Where(x => x.DateAndTimeOfSession < form.BookingDate.Date.AddDays(1)) // <--
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

Take off the .Date
If the field is a DateTime it can be compared with ==

```
var duplicate = from a in _db.AgentProductTraining
                where a.CourseCode == course.CourseCode &&
                a.DateTaken == course.DateTaken &&
                a.SymNumber == symNumber
                select a;
```