# Perform search by Date using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I try to make search query in Entity framework. I have table Project with 'Id', 'ProjectName', 'Description' and "modificationdate" etc. I want to perform search on 'ProjecName', 'Description' and "modificationdate". I successfully perform search on 'ProjectName' & 'Description' but i don't know how perform search by date

```
var found = from n in context.Project
                            where n.projectName.Contains(SearchKey) ||
                            n.description.Contains(SearchKey) 
                        select n;
```

Comment: Have a look At Entity Functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What's the problem with something like `|| n.Modification > DateTime.Now` ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is The search would include the time. You need an Entity Function to truncate the time

Comment: @James So get rid of the time `|| n.Modification > DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: This would help also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778758/use-linq-query-to-compare-date-only-with-datetime-field

Answer (score 2):

You can use the greather-than `>`, less-than `<` and equals `==` operators for example (see [this](http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/operators/) for a complete list) to search by date. Example to get projects modified a week ago or less:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) > n.modificationdate
```

If you don't want to include the time, you can use the `Date` property to exclude it:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date > n.modificationdate.Date
```

**Edit:** search by given date:

```
date == n.modificationdate
```

Where `date` is the given date. If the date is specified in the `SearchKey` variable (which I assume is a `string`), you have to parse it to a date first.

Comment: This would be inaccurate without truncating the time as is if you search at 2pm, the search will not pull back items from 7 days ago at 1pm.

Comment: The point is you are still having partial days due to time. Just truncate the time and provide a more accurate search

Comment: I've updated my question with a note to the `Date` property of `DateTime`.

Comment: *facepalm* you still have a time on the modificationdate!

Comment: @James A minor typo on my behalf. If you want everything that changed from yesterday (i.e. one day ago) then subtract one day and use the date and compare with `>=`. So if something was modified `27/10/2013 1:00pm` then `28/10/2013 - 1 Day` is `27/10/2013 12:00am`. There's no need for entity functions.

Comment: Actually i try to perform search on given date

Comment: @Vicky you could use `date == n.modificationdate` for that. Where `date` is the variable containing the given date.

Answer (score 2):

To take what you're saying from the comments:

> Actually i try to perform search on given date

If you want to search for modifications on a given date, just search for values greater than or equal to the start of the date and then everything less than the day after.

```
var searchDate = new DateTime(2013, 2, 5); // or searchDateWithTime.Date
var searchDatePlusOne = searchDate.AddDays(1);

return from n in context.Project
       where n.ModificationDate >= searchDate
             && n.ModificationDate < searchDatePlusOne
       select n;
```

If `n.ModificationDate` contains a date and nothing more, then `n.ModificationDate == searchDate` is a sufficient predicate.